# Matlab GUI Compatibility Between Mac and Windows (Display)

Tags: windows, macos, matlab, user-interface, compatibility

For some time now, I've been working on a series of GUIs. I use a Mac running OSX to write all of my code, and the problem I've encountered is that it there are deviations in appearance when the GUIs are used in windows, some of which are minor, and some of which are very significant.

1) The text in the windows version is substantially larger overall. This results in some of my button titles simply going off the button, or panel titles moving beyond the panel.

2) Axes appear to be different dimensions between Mac and Windows. i.e. An axis that appears square on my Mac will appear elongated or rectangular on windows, and vice versa.

3) Graphical displays are different. This is the real problem. Some of my GUIs use axes to display text and model chemical reaction animations. On the Mac, they look perfectly fine, but on the windows system, the sizing is completely off.

I've set all "Units" to "characters" as suggested by the Mathworks help page, and I do not specify any fonts to allow each system to use its default. I have however, specified font sizes, but apparently, 12 point font on windows appears very different from 12 point font on mac.

Are there any ways around these problems? I thought setting a specified font size and allowing for use of default fonts would fix this, but it hasn't, and I'm a little dry for ideas at this point.

Comment: I assume that you're using the same version of Matlab on OS X and on Windows? Also, what fonts are you using? Helvetica is a default for OS X, but I'm not sure Windows has it. These sorts of things have never been Matlab's forté.

Comment: Yes, Matlab 2012 on both.

Comment: And when I performed a debug and checked the fonts that were being generated, both windows and OSX used Helvetica. Even when I manually set the font to times, the displays were still different.

Comment: I'd suggest that you break this question up. Come up with simple example code that we can run that demonstrates each issue as it pertains to your use.

Answer (score 0):

Try working in 'pixels' or absolute size units instead of 'characters', and apply a scaling factor to your font sizes.

Setting 'Units' to 'characters' is probably the wrong way to go for portability, and could be the main cause of your display sizing issues. Which specific Matlab page recommended that you do so? Was it talking about cross-platform portability? The `characters` unit is very convenient to work with, but it is tied to the font metrics for the default system font. (See the doco for Units property at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html). That's going to differ between different operating systems. Working with 'pixels' or inches/centimeters/points, which are absolute, will probably give you more uniform results across operating systems.

And you're not wrong: OS X tends to display fonts of a given size on screen smaller than Windows does. (Generally; YMMV depending on your display DPI and system settings and other things.) For example, I run my terminals and text editors at 10 or 12 points in Windows, but 14 point or larger on Mac. So apply a scaling factor to the font sizes you set in your GUI. Figure out what looks good on Mac, and then scale it in your code to something like `windows_font_size = floor(mac_font_size * 0.8)` and see how it goes.

If you want to be more precise in scaling, you could grab the `ScreenPixelsPerInch` and `ScreenSize` root properties with `get(0,...)`. You may also be able to call down in to Java code to get precise font metrics info to help with font scaling choices.

Either way, you're going to have to test your code on both systems instead of just expecting it to work portably. If you don't have ready access to a Windows development system, consider setting up a Windows VM on your Mac. With file sharing between the two sides, you'll be able to try your code out on both platforms right as you work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well. 
Calling this function within the `FUNCTIONNAME_OpeningFcn` might alleviate your issues:

```
function decreaseFontSizesIfReq(handles)
% make all fonts smaller on a non-mac-osx computer
persistent fontSizeDecreased
fontSizeDecreased = [];
if ~ismac()
    % No MAC OSX detected; decrease font sizes
    if isempty(fontSizeDecreased)
        for afield = fieldnames(handles)'
            afield = afield{1}; %#ok<FXSET>
            try %#ok<TRYNC>
                set(handles.(afield),'FontSize',get(handles.(afield),'FontSize')*0.75); % decrease font size
            end
        end
        fontSizeDecreased=1; % do not perform this step again.
    end
end
```